Select date on calendar using selenium in python 3
While trying to get chromedriver in selenium to select a date in the calendar, I'm stuck with a hidden field for the date.
I've used the following code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


url = "https://www.fpi.nsdl.co.in/web/Reports/Archive.aspx"
date_value = '2024-06-04'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

try:
    date_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hdnDate"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('type')", date_button)
    uh_date_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hdnDate"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", uh_date_button, date_value)
    date_button.click()
    
    # Click on the "view report" button
    view_report_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a[1]/div[2]')
    view_report_button.click()

    # Click on the "export to excel" button
    export_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a[2]/div[2]')
    export_button.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page elements to load")
    
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


It gets stuck in calendar and doesn't do anything
I expected to be able to select a date on calendar and populate the page. My non working code is given above

are there issues if you try to just click on the calendar? because now youre using javascript to remove and set attributes, and that might not work at all for a variety of reasons.

The reason for trying to set attributes is cause that particular element has type=hidden set. I had tried to send a date before that, without modifying the type, but it did nothing.

Check the working code below with explanation:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.fpi.nsdl.co.in/web/Reports/Archive.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Below 2 lines will click on calendar icon and click on 11th of current month
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "imgtxtDate"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='DynarchCalendar-bodyTable']//div[text()='11']"))).click()

# Click View Report
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnSubmit1"))).click()

# Click Export to Excel
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnExcel"))).click()
time.sleep(10)

Explanation of the XPath:
//table[@class='DynarchCalendar-bodyTable']//div[text()='11']

You can use above XPath to locate and click on the specific day of the month. This XPath locates the 11th of current month. If you want some other day just change the day. For example, to select 12June2024, change the number to 12.
On another note, suggestion: Avoid using absolute XPaths like below. They are brittle and not reliable. You should use relative XPaths instead(like the ones used in my answer).
/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a[1]/div[2]


Yes it works correctly. How did you get the calendar xpath?  Cause I would like to extend it to be able to click for other years and months
